# Encrypting and comparing hashes

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash

Checked a lot of tutorials and guides about Encrypting and Hashing on StackOver and I do now understand the difference between both of them.
Encryption when we need decryption. Hash when you don't (e.g: passwords).

But my question today is, for generating random unique tokens. A lot of people recommend using base64_encode(rand_bytes(32)); because it generates a secure cryptographical id with random bytes/letters so it takes a long time to be cracked by a brute force ( to be predicted ).

But when you, for example, hash_hmac or crypt that id will it make it weaker?
If so it won't matter if you use mt_rand or random_bytes as it will generate other letters/id. So what do you guys recommend?

Also, Is crypt better than hash_hmac for hashing?

The last question, Since blowfish has a really strong hashing algorithm, do I need to store my, for example, PHPSESSID or CSRF token with it or just a normal random_bytes?

Please guys, provide me with detailed information about these questions or documentation.
Sorry for my lack of information and inexperience, I am new to PHP coding and thanks!

Edit: I have seen some guides on SO, not covering all my questions, so I need a 2017 detailed information not a 10 years ago post where md5 was the best etc..!

Comment: For hashing, you should use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and then [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when you want to verify a hash. When generating tokens or similar, you should use [random_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

Comment: Alright, so, I don't need to hash the random_bytes(), but for hashing is hash_hmac better or crypt? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: You don't need to hash the random bytes, but since you'll get random _bytes_, you probably need to convert it to something like hex: `bin2hex(random_bytes(32))`, for example. For hashing, you should use `password_hash()`, which I also mentioned. That's using BCRYPT as default and generates a secure salt for you.

Comment: Aha, thanks and -> bin2hex not base64_encode? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: bin2hex, base64... it doesn't matter. It's just a way to convert the string to a readable format. It's still the same random string.

Comment: Ahh, thanks bro for explaining, I have one more question, is it good to loop over the random_bytes so it becomes slower and takes time to be cracked by a brute force attack? for(i=0; i<10000; $i++) ? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: bin2hex and base64_encode are both suitable as they are both a textual representation of binary data. Base64 generates some shorter output, but may contain non-url-safe characters (`+`, `=`, `/`) - so depends on your situation which one is the best for you

Comment: You don't "crack" random byte-strings. Random bytes simply generates a random string of n:th length. A random string is a random string, regardless of how many times you iterate it. It's all about the length and possible variations. It's the _hash_ that can be brute forced and password_hash() has a `cost`-option that you should tweak to fit the server it's gonna be run on (dependent on CPU etc). Security wise, the higher cost is better, but you don't want it to take like 2-3 seconds to hash or verify a hash (that wouldn't be particular scaleable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When you just want tokens that are unpredictable, use [`random_bytes(32)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php).** *As long as you keep the tokens secret*, there is no reason to alter the result of this function.

> But you ask a lot of specific questions, so I will try to answer them as best I can:

### When you hash or `crypt()` that id will it make it weaker?

This depends on the HMAC or crypt routine. When you generate 32 bytes of random data, and then use a function to reduce the size to 16 bytes, the security will be halved. However, if you use a *cryptographically secure* function that has at least 32 bytes of output, the security is not reduced. Now I say this, because **[`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) is not cryptographically secure function**. **When hashing passwords, use [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead.**

### Is there a difference between using `mt_rand` and using `random_bytes`?

*Yes, it **will** matter.* [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) uses a Mersenne Twister random number generator. These are not secure. This means that an attacker could use token values to guess other tokens. In the case of `mt_rand()`, this is often very easy. If you need the tokens to be secure (authentication tokens, session cookies, CSRF tokens, id's that may not be enumerated, etc.), use [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php). Also, if you are not sure, use `random_bytes`.

### Also, Is crypt better than hash_hmac for hashing?

**No.** Crypt is deprecated and you should not use it. Use HMAC when you need message authentication codes (for example for password reset URLs). For password hashing, use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

### Do I need to store my, for example, PHPSESSID or CSRF token with Blowfish or just a normal `random_bytes`?

Just use `random_bytes`. The random data is already random, it does not need to be randomized again. At least, as long as you keep these tokens secret and revoke them immediately when they have been leaked.

Comment: So, we have 3 levels of security. 1-) Passwords, It should be password_hash to be strongly secure. 2-) Password-Reset links should be hashed with, for example, hash_hmac to be a little more unpredictable. 3-) CSRF with normal random_bytes without hashing as it is still secure, not too secure but less likely to be predicted, and won't lead to "Denial Of Service" after it is predicted, right? Also, is it good to hash_hmac twice? I use sha512 for hash_hmac. @Daan Sprenkels

Comment: These are *not* levels of security. They are different contexts, with different requirements. The reason you are using `password_hash` is because you do not want an attacker to be able to get the passwords after a database breach. HMAC is used in context when there is a secret key and you want authentication on a piece of data. Reset links can also be done by generating random data and storing the tokens in the database. CSRF tokens do **not** protect against DoS, but against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)). Finally, why would you use HMAC twice?

Comment: Check my new comment down below

Answer (score 2):

Hashing can't make your tokens any stronger or more random, there is no way to increase the entropy of a really random token or to improve it otherwise.

The only moment hashing a token makes sense, is when it is stored in the session/database (the client always should get the original token). Storing a hash in the database, will protect the tokens in case of a stolen database (SQL-injection).

In contrast to "weak" user passwords, "strong" random tokens cannot be successfully brute-forced, therefore salting and key-stretching is not necessary. One can use a simple fast hash function like SHA-256, which keeps the hashes searchable. When the client makes a request, the original token can be hashed again and the stored hash can be searched for.

Comment: That's what key-stretching means, the token is hashed several times to increase the necessary time to calculate a single hash, it is a counter measure to brute-forcing. In case of tokens key-stretching is not necessary, because brute-forcing a token with enough entropy is out of question. So no, double hashing is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, alright. That makes sense. Thanks for everything bro!

Comment: @hobaa - Let's do some math, a 32 byte token can represent 1E77 combinations. If we assume that the hash can be calculated with 100Giga hashes per second, we can still expect 1.8E58 years to find the hash, a number with 59 digits! Of course this only applies to truly random tokens.

Comment: @martinstoeckili Check my post up please ;)

Answer (score -1):

@martinstoeckli Bro, you are amazing, I understood everything that you described clearly as you deeply explained everything. To double sure that I have it clear, check my code!

1-) Random tokens which have no hashes and is not stored in a database like CSFR tokens

```
$random_code = base64_encode(random_bytes(32)); //without hashing
```

2-) Remember Me - Client will have the random_code, and in the database, I have the hashed token stored.

example for remember_me

```
$random_code = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));

            $token = hash_hmac('sha256', ($random_code . $username) , $random_code);
            $token = hash_hmac('sha256', $random_code , $token);


      setcookie("remember", $username . "|" . $random_code, time()+(60 * 60 * 24 * 7), "/", "", 1, 1); //1 week
```

Comment: Why do you store all the information in a cookie, actually it would be more safe if only the random token is stored client side, and all other information like expiration date remains server side. On my homepage I published a small [example](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) how reset tokens can be handled.

Comment: @martinstoeckli actually this is what I did, let me explain my code. The random_code is generated and stored in the cookie with the username, it is not stored in the database. A hashed token of the random_code is stored in the database with the username. When the user loads the website, the random_code is hashed the same way, if it matches the token in the database, then it is valid.  It is a Remember Me not Reset Password.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your intent, sorry. Still, there is no need for the hmac s, the `$random_code` can directly be stored in the cookie as you actually did, so what is the `$token` for? A hmac combines a secret key with a message, but there is no secret key in your code. For storing the random code in the database you can simply call `$hashForDatabase = hash('sha256', $random_code, false)`.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Sorry, I got a little bit confused. So, what you mean is that the random_code remains in the cookie and the hashed version of the random_code which is the token should be stored in the database this way? I thought that the $username is the secret key and that with hash_hmac it is a better way of hashing it.

Comment: Usually the random code which is passed to the client is called token, that got me on the wrong track in my first comment. We calculate a hash for the case that an attacker can read the database, he would then know the token and could fake the cookie. When we store only a hash of the token, there is no way to get the original randomcode/token, so it is not possible to fake the cookie. The hmac does not add any security, simply said it makes sure that the hash can only be calculated if the username is known to the attacker, which is the case in our scenario.

Comment: @martinstoeckli Ahh, yeah! So, I will use the code you provided me, and sorry for confusing you with the token thing. Thanks for everything bro. God bless you! If you have any important notes for me, feel free to say whatever you want to make me better!